# C - I can't get my stringcopy and stringcat function to work on a 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, string.h

I'm trying to combine a char type 2d array with a string (specifically "*") and a number which is already in the form of a string.

Let's say I have a list of numbers (that have a string datatype) on a 2d array called bingo `char bingo[n][n]`, I then wanted to copy this to a new 2d array called `char finalbingo[n][n]` along with a "*" with a stringcopy and strcat function.

(e.g: bingo[0][0] contain a  string "5", this will become "*5" on finalbingo)

Here is my code:

```
int l,m,q;
char number;
char finalbingo[n][n];

for (l = 0; l < n; l++){
    for (m = 0; m < n; m++){
          number = bingo[l][m];
          strcpy(&finalbingo[l][m], "*");
          strcat(&finalbingo[l][m], &number);
    }
  }
 
 printf("%c", finalbingo[0][0]);
```

It does not seem to be working and I'm not sure why.
Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Did u also declare the ```int n``` variable because i only see l, m and q.

Comment: Each element of the 2D array can only hold a single character. Also, `strcpy` and `strcat` work on null-terminated strings, not individual characters.

Comment: You may want `char finalbingo[n][n][4];` and `snprintf(finalbingo[l][m], sizeof(finalbingo[l][m]), "*%c", number);`